# Custom CollectionView cells aren't being selected, but registers selection outside of the cell space

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

[image: view example]

In the example above, clicking into the blue cell does not fire off any of the collectionView delegate methods eg "didSelectItem". But clicking into the remaining white space directly to the left of it will. It is a custom cell with essentially just the textview on top of a UIView with a blue background. Is this the expected behavior?

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    cell.textView.text = message.text

    setupCell(cell: cell, message: message)

    if let text = message.text {
     cell.bubbleWidthAnchor?.constant = estimateFrameForText(text: text).width + 32
    } else if message.imageUrl != nil {
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor?.constant = 200
    }

    return cell
}

private func setupCell(cell: ChatMessageCell, message: Message) {
    if let profileImageUrl = self.user?.profileImageUrl {
        cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: profileImageUrl)
    }

    if message.fromId == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = ChatMessageCell.blueColor
        cell.textView.isHidden = false
        cell.textView.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = true
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = true

        cell.bubbleViewRightAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.bubbleViewLeftAnchor?.isActive = false
    } else {
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220)
        cell.textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = true

        cell.bubbleViewRightAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.bubbleViewLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
    }

    if let messageImageUrl = message.imageUrl {
        cell.messageImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: messageImageUrl)
        cell.textView.isHidden = true
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    } else {
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = true
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var height: CGFloat = 80

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    if let text = message.text {
        height = estimateFrameForText(text: text).height + 18
    } else if let imageWidth = message.imageWidth?.floatValue, let imageHeight = message.imageHeight?.floatValue {

        height = CGFloat(imageHeight / imageWidth * 200)

    }

    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

private func estimateFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
    let size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 1000)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin) // look this up on stack overflow

    return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil)
}
```

Comment: Make sure in your custom collectionView Cell all the UIComponents that you added to decorate cell like bubbleView,messageImageView have their `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to false, also for textView `isEditable` is unchecked.

Comment: That was precisely it!